# Programmatically create a shadow copy on Win XP

Tags: windows-xp, volume-shadow-copy

In Vista / 7 I can create a shadow copy with vssadmin (VSSADMIN.EXE version 1.1)

```
vssadmin create shadow /For=c:
```

In XP, vssadmin version is 1.0, and doesn't support the `create` command, only `list`

Then, how can I create a volumen shadow copy for a complete backup?

Answer (score 2):

Shadow copies are non-persistent in XP:

> The Volume Snapshot Service was first added to Microsoft Windows in Windows XP; this version of VSS is used by NTBackup, however it can only create non-persistent snapshots (a temporary snapshot, usually used for creating a file-based backup or more generally, accessing copies of files that have been locked by applications for editing).

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy#Windows_XP_and_Windows_Server_2003)

Comment: but if NTBackup or DriveImageXML can create a shadow copy of the volume, isn't there an Win32 API available to do it?

Comment: I suppose there is, but I think it's more that in XP VSS can only be used to make temporary file shadows so that they can be backed up if they're open, and/or to prevent backup failure from affecting the files being backed-up.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this seems to be the (supposedly Public Domain) tool known as vscsc, found here: http://vscsc.sourceforge.net/

Shadow copies on XP are only temporary, but that's the simplest way to use them.